# Restore for inApp for non-consumable product in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

Is it compulsory to add restore button in the UI for restoring the inApp purchase for non consumable product.

Is there any way to do it automatically like in Angry Birds and other apps/games?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by Apple in [In-App Purchase Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf):

**Designing Your In-App Purchase Store**

Your In-App Purchase store should be attractive, easy to understand, and simple to use. Follow these design guidelines to help you meet this goal:

Provide a “Check Inventory” button that allows users to check for items they might be missing or that they’ve already purchased on another device. Keep in mind that automatically initiating a restore of previous purchases (which will prompt the user for their iTunes Store password) may be confusing to your users.

In code, call `restoreCompletedTransactions()` method to implement this.

Answer (score 4):

Yes the reason is because is a non-consumable, it makes sense since removing and reinstall the app will make the user to lose the purchase, so you need to include an option to restore the non-consumables:

Please Refer the following link for that [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/MakingaPurchase/MakingaPurchase.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH3-SW2)

**Personal Experience**

In my one game i integrate in-app purchase in that non-consumable IAP installed and apple reject my app and insert one restore button for the restore purchase and now app in review.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I am getting the error while purchasing the product that :you are not authorized to purchase this app.Any idea y this error occurs